# iOS app build status is "Processing" on itunes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I am facing issue from 2 days that i am uploading a build on itunes with application loader and it always shows error

> The session's status is FAILED and the error description is 'failed to open ssh session. (14)'
>
> An exception has occurred: The transport has been detected as having stalled and has been aborted.  Please try again

means it is not uploaded but when i logged in in to the ituens account and select project build there is showing that build status "Processing" and not be selectable.

Please help me out if any one face this type of issue.

Comment: Did you checked your firewall settings?

Comment: The "Processing" status is a false friend, it is shown even when the upload failed or when you uploaded a invalid binary. You should check if you get desired connections to the apple servers as Gowtham already pointed out. You get a list of ports apple uses here https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT202944

Comment: If you failed to upload to iTunesConnect in the middle of the submission, there's still chance iTunesConnect still shows that submission and "Processing".

Comment: set Enable Bitcode to NO for Debug option in application. And then try to upload a app on app store.

Comment: Hello guys thanks for reply
gowtham and dan i did above operation regarding firewall setting but still i am facing same issue.

And Krupanshu i am uploading with xocde 6.1 so ia have no option for bitcode setting.   Please suggest different method.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have uploaded invalid binary or upload build process has been interrupted

You can resubmit the build.

You can also use Application Loader https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf